# querySelector returns null, how to reach a div inside another template?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I have the following HTML file for a LWC (details omitted):

```
<template>
  <div id="main-div">
... (A)
  </div>
  <template if:true={xyz}>
... (B)
  </template>
</template>
```

In the JS code I want to change the style of the div, when a button in (B) is clicked. When I try this code:

```
this.template.querySelector('main-div').setAttribute('style', 'overflow:visible;');
```

I get the runtime error that `this.template.querySelector('main-div')` returns null. How can I reach the div just above (A) from inside (B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id selector does not work with LWC, you can use "class" attribute instead like below:

In Html:

```
  <div class="main-div">
... (A)
  </div>
```

In Js:

```
this.template.querySelector('.main-div').style = 'overflow:visible;';
```

Comment: Quoting from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work), Id selector doesn't work because: `Don’t use ID selectors with querySelector. The IDs that you define in HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it won’t match the transformed ID.`